# Links not working after being rendered from xml and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I have a basic news ticker that loads on index.html
It pulls div information from xml file and auto changes the data on ticker screen.  It pauses on hover and has forward and back buttons

Everything works great if the feed is just plain text, I however cannot seem to get the ticker to accept a link that is clickable.  The clickable link should change background and open up a popup window with further information
this works with a manual link on the page

I am able to get the link to show either by cdata on the xml file or working the "a href" into the jquery that adds the xml data to the page with appropriate div's

if i manually add the div with the link to the html page, the link works fine

after the js code the following is added to the html :

```
<div class="newsTicker active"><a href="#" id="open">Latest News updates/ticker 1</a></div>
<div class="newsTicker">Latest News updates/ticker 2</div>
<div class="newsTicker">Latest News updates/ticker 3</div>
<div class="newsTicker">Latest News updates/ticker 4</div>
```

when I inspecte the page the information is being entered into the page correctly yet the link does not work
can someone please help!!

main ticker found here---> http://jsfiddle.net/17h0wa28/5/

xml page is very basic so that non technical people can update it on the fly if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NEWSFEED>
    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE><![CDATA[<a href="#" id="open">Latest News updates/ticker 1</a>]]></UPDATE>
    </STATUS>
    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 2</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>
    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 3</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>
    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 4</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>
</NEWSFEED>
```

Comment: Your fiddle wasn't working completely. **[Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/17h0wa28/6/)**. Can you please explain more on the problem?

Comment: thanks for that,  now that the link is showing, the propblem is the the link does not work.  the design is, when you click on the link the page should fade in a background along with a popup window to provide additional informaiton.  unfortunately the link just changes colors and does not open the popup windows at this time...

Comment: Have you written any code for pop up window to appear?

Comment: in the fiddle js code starts at line 101 for the fadeIn and out based on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got your problem.. Since your anchor tag gets generated dynamically i.e. appends to `DOM` after its been completely loaded, you need to have **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**, to attach `events` to `dynamically` added `elements`, something like below:

Your code for click of `#open` element should be modified as:

```
$(document).on('click','#open',function(e) { //event delegation
   e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action if necessary
   $('#pop_background').fadeIn();
   $('#pop_box').fadeIn();
   return false;
});
```

Attach `event` to `document` and then identify if that click was from `#open` element.  Also if you have any other static elements to which your #open will be loaded, say `dynamic elements` are appended to already existing `elements` in `DOM`, then you can give `id` of that `static element`

Comment: Thanks so very much, I figured it had something to do with the fact that the anchors were being created later in the load process.  You are awesome!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)